# How to get the number of team members for a Project?

Tags: rally

I created an app using the 2.0 API in which I need to gather the number of team members contributing to each project. Currently, the way I am calculating this number is by looking at the number of unique owners of tasks within that project. Today I noticed that when I was looking at my permissions for each project, it had a field for "Team Member" which listed me as part of teams I had been added to. I was curious if this field is accessible via the API for getting the number of team members for each project, or if it's only visible on a user-by-user basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK does have a way of accessing the number of Team Members in each project. The way I did it is to query through all the Projects, grabbing the number of team members from there.

Here's the code of how I did that:

```
Ext.define('TeamMemberCountApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'Project',
            fetch: ['Name', 'TeamMembers', 'FirstName', 'LastName'],
            autoLoad: true,
            context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
            listeners: {
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },

    _onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
        var records = [];

        Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
            var teamName = record.get('Name');
            var teamMembersList = record.get('TeamMembers');

            records.push({
                Name: teamName,
                TeamMembers: teamMembersList
            });

            console.log('Number of members in Team ' + teamName + ' is ' + teamMembersList.Count);
        });
    }
});
```

The store will contain the number of Team Members which is a regular Javascript array. These objects will hold the _ref values of the User object.

The fetch property in the data store is recursive which means it can grab the first and last names of team members despite grabbing a project model. To create a full User model, I believe you need to use a [ModelFactory](http://developer.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.ModelFactory) though I'm not 100% on that.

In terms of team members actually working on a user story/defect/task, your method of looking at the owner of each of those artifacts seems fine. The code above will only show the team members in a project, regardless of what they're working on.

For future reference, [this](http://developer.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/source/ModelTypes.html#Rally-data-ModelTypes) source code link in the docs contains all the model types that can be used from a simple string (such as 'user' or 'defect').

Comment: Thank you for this :) I had no idea the Project model kept track of an array of team members. Is there a page I can look at for each model that will give me all of the fields within that model? Thanks again!

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. I personally used console.log() to see what fields are available to a model.

Comment: Likewise, I've been doing it the same way. Just seems like something that would be (should be) included in the documentation. Good to know I wasn't adding unnecessary complexity to the situation though.

Comment: As a side note here is the [page](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#Project) in our documentation that shows what fields exist on an object.